# Regex extract paragraphs of specific pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a log with pattern as follows:

```
2018-06-08 11:32:06 INFO 1 Global.asax - Service Starting
2018-06-08 11:33:06 INFO 1 Blah Blah Blah Blah
    Blah Blah Blah
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2018-06-08 11:34:06 INFO 1 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

I would like to extract the following result with regular expression:

```
2018-06-08 11:32:06 INFO 1 Global.asax - Service Starting
```

And

```
2018-06-08 11:33:06 INFO 1 Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

And

```
2018-06-08 11:34:06 INFO 1 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

This is the closest result i've tried so far

```
(\d{4})[\D](\d{2})[\D](\d{2})[\s](\d{2})(\D)(\d{2})(\D)(\d{2}).*+
```

Comment: Please include your JavaScript code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Oh i was close, here is the answer.

<del>(\d{4})\D\D\s(\D)(\d{2})(\D)(\d{2})[\s\S]+?(?=(\d{4})\D\D\s(\D)(\d{2})(\D)(\d{2})|\Z)</del>

**Thanks for the update from Toto**

```
\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}[\s\S]+?(?=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}|\Z)
```

Comment: Why all these capture groups and useless character class? `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}[\s\S]+?(?=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}|\Z)` is enough.

Comment: @Toto - `[\s\S]`? I know that was in the expression in this answer, but doesn't that match any character?

Comment: @nnnnnn: Yes it does. It matches all character including linebreak.

Comment: @Toto Tried on javascript and it's missing the last line, seems \z is not working on javascript. Any alternatives? Thank you.